# How to prove $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ using the definition of expectation $E(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, expectation

Please someone help me to prove the following theorem:
$$\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)$$
using the definition of expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)$

My proof:
$$\mathbb{E}(X+Y) = \sum_{x} \sum_{y}(x+y)P_{XY}(x,y)$$
$$= \sum_{x} \sum_{y}xP_{XY}(x,y) + \sum_{x} \sum_{y}yP_{XY}(x,y)$$
$$= \sum_{x} xP_{X}(x) + \sum_{y}yP_{Y}(y)$$
$$=\mathbb{E}(X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)$$

Is this proof right?

Comment: It looks right :)

Comment: You have used discrete random variables.  The general case is similar but can get more complicated

Comment: Maybe the equation you use, $\sum_yP_{XY}(x,y)=P_X(x)$, should be emphasized and spelled out a bit..

Comment: @Berci what do I say?

Comment: You are not starting from your own definition of expectation... For discrete random variables, your first formula for $E(X+Y)$, which you should then work on, should be $$E(X+Y)=\sum_zzP_{X+Y}(z)$$ Instead, you are starting from $$E(X+Y)=\sum_{x,y}(x+y)P_{X,Y}(x,y)$$ and, frankly, in the logic of your question, one does not know how you would know that this holds...

Answer (score 3):

Proposition:

Let $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ and $Y\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be random variables in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and let $\alpha$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$E(\alpha X+\beta Y)=\alpha E(X)+\beta E(Y).$$

Proof:

$$E(\alpha X+\beta Y)=\int_{\Omega}(\alpha X +\beta Y) d\mathbb{P}=\alpha\int_{\Omega}X d\mathbb{P} + \beta\int_{\Omega}Y d\mathbb{P}=\alpha E(X)+\beta E(Y).$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this notation.  What does $\int_{\Omega}(\alpha X + \beta Y)d\mathbb{P}$ mean?

Comment: Well, X and Y are functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha$,$\beta$ are real constants and we are integrating their ''linear combination'' with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. Hope this answers your question!